# Moving a certain node in a linked list forward n positions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to move a node forward n positions in a linked list

e.g

list : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Moving '2' forward 3 positions

New list: 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6

This is what I tried

```
void MoveNodeForward(Node* head, int x, int n)
{
    Node* t = head;

    while(t != NULL)
    {
        if(t->data == x)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<n && t->next != NULL; i++)
            {
                int temp = t->next->data;
                t->next->data = t->data;
                t->data = temp;
                t = t->next;
            }
        }

        t = t->next;
    }

}
```

But it just swaps the value of the nodes.

I need a way to change the position of the node itself not just the value.

Comment: Take the node-to-be-moved out of the list, move forward by the n positions, and then insert the node-to-be-moved into that position.

Comment: That's exactly what you're doing. swapping the "data" member. I'm not sure how that is any different from swapping the node pointers (which you could have done instead) in the final result, since your interface uses the data values.

Comment: @KennyOstrom It's not about the final result, it's about using references and pointers.

Comment: Is your linked list single- or double-linked? Implementation will differ in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void move_n_position(struct node **p1,int position,int n)//n is the no of time moving front
{
int i;
struct node *bef=NULL;
struct node *prev=NULL;
struct node *temp=*p1;

for(i=1;i<position;i++)
{
    prev=temp;

temp=temp->link;


}

if(prev!=NULL)
{
bef=temp;
prev->link=bef->link;
}
else
{
    bef=temp;
    (*p1)=(*p1)->link;

}

i=0;
while(i<n)
{

 temp=temp->link;
 i++;
}

bef->link=temp->link;
temp->link= bef;
}
```

Comment: Although probably correct (IDK), please add some text explaining what it does. Just pasting code is considered bad.